# How can i redirect to another page without loading the current page in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mean-stack

I want to redirect to another page without loading the currentpage.

let me  explain  my task. I am having user login condition.

If the user has not  login and he tries to enter the URL directly EX("localhost/sample.html") means it will come to login page. For me this condition is working nicely.

First sample.html page open and then only it will redirect to login. The user able to see the Data in sample.html.

```
var logincheck = function () {
    debugger;
    $http.get('loggedin').success(function (user) {
        alert(user);
        // Authenticated
        if (user != '0') {
            refresh();
            return;

        }
            // Not Authenticated
        else {
            $window.location.href = '/';
        }
    });
};
logincheck();
```

Is there any way to go login page without loading the sample.html page.

Answer (score 0):

A interesting way do to this is by checking this condition in a [$route event](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route). For example, you can write this code in your `app.run`:

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
    if(next.$$route && userNotAuthenticated) {
        $location.href('/');
    }
});
```

The advantage is that it will work for your whole app, you won't have to write code for each page.

Answer (score 0):

In your main controller (the one attached to index) you should do a login check and set a variable to true/false. In your controller do a check on this variable, and do a $state.go() if user is not logged in.

Use ng-cloak directive in your index file where you attach your main controller like:

```
<body ng-controller="mainController" ng-cloak>
```

You can read up on ng-cloak [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it.

Whenever your angular app is boots, it runs the `run` function. So attach a location change listener in that function like below

```
App.run(['$rootScope', '$http', '$urlRouter', function($rootScope, $http, $urlRouter) {
  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();// prevents the location change
    $http({// make a http call to check if user is logged in or not.
      url: '/path/to/check/auth',
      method: 'post',
      data: {}
    }).then(function(response){
      if(response.data.isUserLoggedIn){//If user is logged in.
        $urlRouter.sync();
      }else{//user is not logged in
        window.location.assign('/login');
      }
    }, function() {
      window.location.assign('/login');
    });
  });
  $urlRouter.listen();
}]);
```